# Restoring Firefox private window after a power outage

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

After the outage I did not start the browser yet. I hope there is something I can do before that to retrieve the information I lost.
I lost about 20 tabs.

Anything I can do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can recover a Private Browsing session.

> All session data is kept in memory during PB mode and nothing is stored in the Firefox profile folder.
>   The disk cache is disabled as well and only the memory cache is used, so you can't find any data there as well.
>   That is the risk when running in PB mode and you run into problems like a hang or crash that you can't recover from this and lose all data.

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1069013#answer-746031